# Conditional Validation in Java

Tags: java, validation, server-side, bean-validation

I am trying to do bean validation in a Object graph. Lets say I have two classes called Foo and Bar. They have @OneToOne relationship.

Foo.class

```
class Foo
{
    String a;
    String b;
    boolean c;

    @Valid
    Bar bar;
}
```

Bar.class

```
class Bar
{
    String i;
    String j;
    String k;
    String l;
}
```

I want to validate Both Foo and Bar but I want to do conditional validation on Bar depending on the value entered in Foo.class. Depending on the value of c in Foo.class, I want to validate the fields in Bar.class. If c is true, then I want to validate i and j. If c is false then I want to validate k and l.

**Is there anyway I can do it?**

Comment: This will be a little difficult since the Bar object has no reference back to its associated Foo instance. Of course you could provide a validate(boolean cIsTrue) method but that may not be what you want. It seems to me you should have two subclasses of Bar, Bar1 and Bar 2. Bar1 would contain only an i and a j and know how to validate itself, while Bar2 has a k and an l. It's often a 'code smell' to have a class that either uses some fields and has one kind of behavior, or another set of fields and a different behavior.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's anything out there that does what you want out of the box. This said, there is [JSR 303](http://beanvalidation.org/1.0/spec/) which allows you to annotate your classes with custom validators. I suppose you could write a validator that can use some custom annotation you'd make and put on the boolean that dictates whether or not to run the Bar validator.

Answer (score 0):

With plain Bean Validation it is not possible to do what you are asking. Hibernate Validator has a provider specific feature which is called `@GroupSequenceProvider`. With this feature you can change the group sequence which gets executed when validating an object. See also http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/validator/reference/en-US/html_single/#d0e3062